# Panda dataframe conditional change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm working on csv time series data, which shows count of step per some time frame. Once the step count is exceeding 65535, it will count start from 0, etc. However since not all the dataset has 65535 count (some goes from 65530, then 5, if they made several steps on the time frame), I can't find a good way to handle it so that every 0 after 6553x will change to 65536.. etc.

```
step    realstep
65531     65531
65533     65533
65534     65534
2         65538
4         65540
```

I'm trying to count the real step in order to get their difference (e.g step/minute).

Comment: I assumed from the sample data that the typical increment in real step was safely much smaller than the max counter value, so that `.diff().lt(0)` was a reliable way to find the reset. Let me know if that's not necessarily the case, as it gets trickier.

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks a lot!

Comment: @ALollz not sure if I have to open new question but as I get through hundreds data set, I realized some 'step' value is just like what you're example is (65534 - 2 - 4 - 65434), while it's actually not (may be noise from sensor) thus it got reset too much. I'm trying to figure how can I remove that kind of row now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find where it resets with `diff` being negative and add the max counter value (65536 since you count from 0) to all rows beyond that. This will be flexible if it resets multiple times (I added some extra data)

```
df['real_step'] = df.step + df.step.diff(1).lt(0).cumsum()*65536

    step  real_step
0  65531      65531
1  65533      65533
2  65534      65534
3      2      65538
4      4      65540
5  65434     130970
6      2     131074
7      4     131076
```

Comment: Awesome, i was wondering what is the logic to be applied here. Learned. Thanks. +1

Comment: @ALollz not sure if I have to open new question but as I get through hundreds data set, I realized some 'step' value is just like what you're example is (65534 - 2 - 4 - 65434), while it's actually not (may be noise from sensor) thus it got reset too much. I'm trying to figure how can I remove that kind of row now.

Comment: @npm I think probably best for a new question. But I think it may be unsolvable. For instance, imagine your data was 2,4,6,8,10... One could assume those were real time-steps and are 2,4,6,8,10. But had you been sampling extremely slowly, those could have also been 2, 65540,131078 (i.e. you had sampled every 65538 seconds). Without more knowledge it's impossible to differentiate the two, and both are logically acceptable.

Comment: @ALoIlz agreed with that. Thanks I'll look for other possibility on using the data!