# Sort or remove specific value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tried to organize this data before doing some analysis, on Python, for example, showing number of step count at a timestamp

[image]

One of the purpose is to calculate step difference for some period (e.g. per minute, per hour), however as it may seen, the step count shows sometimes higher value in between lower value (at 10:48:46) which makes counting the step difference complicated. And to be noted, the count restart to 0 after 65535 (asked here on how to make it readable after 65535: [Panda dataframe conditional change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395647/panda-dataframe-conditional-change) and worked well on nice sorted value).

I know it may be unsolvable because I can't easily remove the unwanted row or sort by value on the column, but hopefully there's any idea to solve this?

Comment: What does our expected output dataframe look like?

Comment: In the next step I would calculate total step per minute, or per hour, by calculating difference between count on the last time stamp - first timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, do you want:

```
 #simple setup
 df = pd.DataFrame({'stepcount':[33,32,41,45,67,76,64,65,69,70,75,76,76,76,76]})

 df[df['stepcount'] >= df['stepcount'].cummax()]
```

Output:

```
    stepcount
0          33
2          41
3          45
4          67
5          76
11         76
12         76
13         76
14         76
```